# Bubble Sort Explanied

Tags: python-3.x, bubble-sort

I'm currently learning bubble sort and I have been given the following code to explain:

```
numbers = [9,5,4,15,3,8,11]
numItems = len(numbers)

for i in range(0,numItems-2):
   for j in range(0,numItems-i-1):
        if numbers[j] > numbers[j+1]:
            temp = numbers[j]
            numbers[j] = numbers[j+1]
            numbers[j+1] = temp
            print(numbers)
```

I do not understand the two for loops, why are they necessary and what they do?

Comment: If you run this code, you'll see the array printed out at each step. This will go some way on its own to answering your question.

Comment: You'll need to understand how bubble sort is working first. Try to google it